# Two column listing separated by a vertical line, LaTeX

Tags: tables, listings, itemize, arrays

I'd like to create something like this:

[image: my notes]

and I achieved similar results in `LaTeX`,

[image]

but nothing is alligned and there is too much white space over and under the text. Any solutions?

Here's the code that I have used

```
\begin{itemize}
    \item[$\impliedby$]
        \begin{center} 
            \begin{tabular}{p{5cm}|p{3.9cm}}
            $\begin{array}{lr}
                    \text{ipotesi: }            [x]_\Rel \ne [y]_\Rel                   \\
                    \text{tesi: \;\;\;\;\;}     [x]_\Rel \cap [y]_\Rel = \varnothing
            \end{array}$
            &
            \begin{lstlisting}
assunto che sia vera l'ipotesi,
supponiamo che la tesi non sia
vera. Dobbiamo arrivare ad una
contraddizione (dimostrazione
per assurdo)
            \end{lstlisting}  
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{itemize}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a single shot you could do this

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb,tabularx}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}l|X@{}}
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}ll>{$}l<{$}@{}}
$\Rightarrow$) & ipotesi: & [x]_{\mathcal{R}} \neq [y]_{\mathcal{R}} \\
               & tesi:    & [x]_{\mathcal{R}} \cap [y]_{\mathcal{R}} = \varnothing
\end{tabular}
&
assunto che sia vera l'ipotesi,
supponiamo che la tesi non sia
vera. Dobbiamo arrivare ad una
contraddizione (dimostrazione
per assurdo)
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternative (using `aligned` instead of a nested `tabular`)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,tabularx}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}l|X@{}}
$
\begin{aligned}[t]
\Rightarrow) \quad & \text{ipotesi:} && [x]_{\mathcal{R}} \neq [y]_{\mathcal{R}} \\
             & \text{tesi:}    && [x]_{\mathcal{R}} \cap [y]_{\mathcal{R}} = \varnothing
\end{aligned}
$
&
Assunto che sia vera l'ipotesi,
supponiamo che la tesi non sia
vera. Dobbiamo arrivare ad una
contraddizione (dimostrazione
per assurdo).
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

(Basically the same output.)

Defining a macro/environment might be smart if you need this kind of construction more often.